# @NotNull annotation is not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, notnull

I am new to Spring Boot and I have this problem.

[image]

and I still get 200 OK even though I don't provide "data"

[image]

Why do you think this is happening?

Any Help is appreciated.

Best

Comment: Its taking data as empty string and not null. Try the api call without any request parameters

Comment: And in your case I think you should use path variable instead and your api should be like `/path/{data}` if its a mandatory parameter

Comment: But I get the same error if I send GET request as /path (without ?data).

Comment: First it should be @RequestParam() not @PathParam check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Comment: Second, if you don't want your api to work without data then you need @PathVariable check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@RequestParam` as opposed to `@PathParams` in this case.
But validation can also be applied to `@PathParam`

```java
@GetMapping(path = "extra")
public String doExtraThing(@RequestParam("data") String data) {
    return "Data is: " + data;
}
```

**Using @NotNull**

If you hit this api directly from browser

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/extra
```

You should get something in the console, because your default request parameter is mandatory.

```
2021-03-06 08:55:20.872  WARN 2936 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'data' is not present]
```

To make it optional use

```java
@RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) String data
```

Now when you try to hit http://localhost:8080/demo/extra?data=, you should get

```
Data is:
```

Now, when you make it `required = false` and add `@NotNull` annotation from `javax.validation.constraints` package and hit the api again you should get 503 internal server error.

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: doExtraThing.data: must not be null
```

**Using @NotBlank**:

You can achieve the same behavior using @NotBlank from `javax.validation.constraints`

[@NotNull](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/NotNullValidator.html) Validate that the object is not null.

[@NotBlank](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/NotBlankValidator.html) check for character sequence's (e.g. string) trimmed length is not empty.

You would use @NotBlank on strings more [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/NotBlankValidator.java)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `@NotNull` you're preventing `String data` to have a null value. But in postman when you're sending data with an empty value, you're actually sending it with an empty String `""`. To prevent both `null` values and empty strings use `@NotBlank`.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/path")
    public String getData(@Valid @PathParam("data") @NotBlank String data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

If you want to send `data` as `null` to check if `@NotNull` works, just uncheck it from the postman params (Don't send it). It should raise an exception in your application that `data` cannot be null.